# jqGrid multipleGroup send query to server

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with the following pager

```
.navGrid('#pager-mm',{add:false,edit:false,del:false,search:true,view:true},
 {},{},{},
 {multipleSearch:true,multipleGroup:true,showQuery: true},
 {})
```

When I build a complex query having nested AND and OR groupings, jqGrid builds the correct query as a string on the client-side.  Rather than rebuilding the same query on my server writing extra code, I would like to send the correctly built client-side query as a string to the server.  However,

```
beforeSumbit:function()
```

is not being triggered when I search.  How can I send this custom string to my server?

Answer (score 2):

I don't full understand what you really want. By default the filters will be send to the server as `filters` parameter. Nevertheless you can use [onSearch](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asinge_searching#options) callback for example to access to the searching filter. You can use

```js
var filters = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData").filters;
```

to get `filters` property of the `postData`.

**UPDATED**: I would **never ever trust the fragment of SQL statement created on the client side**. If you use the SQL fragment which sent from the client in the server code you allow in the way automatically [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). If security play some role in your application you should not use SQL statement created by jqGrid.

Nevertheless if your question have pure theoretical nature you can get the SQL statement displayed in the searching dialog using `toSQLString` method of the searching filter. The corresponding code could look like the following

```js
grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {edit: false, add: false, del: false}, {}, {}, {}, {
    multipleSearch: true,
    multipleGroup: true,
    showQuery: true,
    recreateFilter: true,
    onSearch: function () {
        var $filter = $("#" + $.jgrid.jqID("fbox_" + this.id)),
            sql = $filter.jqFilter('toSQLString');
        alert(sql);
    }
});
```

The corresponding demo you will find [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/displaysqlquery.htm). By the way you don't need to use `showQuery: true` to be able to use `toSQLString` method.

Comment: When I have showQuery:true enabled, the actual query is built on the client side.  Is there a way to pass this query to the server or do I have to rebuild the entire query on the client?  I finally found the "Group" array in the json string to build each group with groupOp and rules, but it would be much easier to just pass the pre-built query to the server.